# Angular 6 - Update *ngIf after Component Loads

Tags: angular, angular6

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Services
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  authorized: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authorized = this.authService.loggedIn();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="authorized"></app-navbar>

<div id="content"
     *ngIf="authorized">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

    <div class="wrapper full-width">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-6"
     *ngIf="!authorized">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`this.authService.loggedIn();` returns true or false, which is used to display some elements in the *ngIf's of the HTML.  The user gets redirected to this page after logging in, so the *ngIf's don't get read automatically.  Instead you have to refresh the page for everything to update properly.

From my knowledge, I can't subscribe to the `this.authService.loggedIn()` due to it not being an observable so I'm not sure how to automatically update the view when the user first views the component.  Here's the service itself for reference:

```
loggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.id_token === undefined ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      const helper = new JwtHelperService();
      return !helper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.id_token);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure that the `authorized` property is up to date by making it a getter:

```
public get authorized(): boolean {
  return this.authService.loggedIn();
}
```

Comment: That seems to work great, but it broke the loading of other components.  Now, when I try to navigate to another route, the route itself changes the the HTML or <router-outlet> content doesn't update until I do a page refresh.

What could be causing the clicked route content to not load?

Comment: This code only gets the current value from the service. I don't know what causes the loading problem. You can check in the console to see if any error is reported.

Comment: Instead of using `ngIf` to hide the router outlet, you may consider implementing a [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) to allow navigation only when the user is logged in.